# The controller for path '/domain/oauth/token' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, asp.net-identity

I've got my authentication with Identity 2.0 working fine for most browsers chrome/firefox/IE11/Edge but it shouts me this error for IE10 and bellow.

I don't understand it. It doesn't implement IController because it's not supposed to, it's configured on startup.cs

```
 private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://domain"),//TODO change url
            RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
        };

        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

        // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    }
```

any idea on why this happens and how to solve the issue to work with older versions of IE or is it simply not possible at all?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

I'm having the exact same issue.